# How do I fix HP Update?

Tags: updates, hp-laptop

I keep getting the HP update running on my computer. When trying to install, it cancels a few seconds after starting. I see the latest update is a fix to fix this behavior, but that does not work either... I doubt I am missing much, just sick of getting the pop-up every week.

Comment: You should try wording your question to not be so General and Vague.

Comment: Which OS? Which version of HP Update? What is it trying to update? itself or other hp software?

Comment: Sorry was at work HP Update v4.000.012.001. Running it on my HP Laptop, 64-bit Vista Ultimate. It has 3 critical updates, 1 updated to 5.2 version of update, and the aforementioned fix for the "cancel" issue is what they call it.

Comment: I had the same problem on a machine I was working on recently.  Also 64-bit Vista, so I don't know if that's the common factor.  I researched and couldn't find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out tonight, though I thought I had done it before. Restarted my laptop with everything turned off (gadgets and such) and opened HP Update myself (Start > HP Update). I unselected all but the "Fix Cancelled Install" patch and clicked next. It downloaded the 512K that it needed, and prompted me to install (normally the downloads cancel). I finished the install with the prompts.

I was then able to start HP Update again, and everything seems to be installing without problems.

Answer (score 0):

same as the guy that said it worked.....thats how mine worked....64-bit vista also.  i only installed the update fix for the update cancellation (all other update unchecked). when i restarted the hp update after it was installed the update software actually updated so no im (in the world of emoticons) colon capital D

Answer (score 0):

I have trying for weeks to update my HP Update v4.000.012.001, running it on my HP Laptop, 32-bit Vista Ultimate. I selected update to 5.2 version of update and  when trying to install, it cancels a few seconds after starting. Any advice will be apreciated

Comment: Did you try clicking on only that update? It wants to try and do all of the updates, but only let it do the update specifically about fixing the update cancellation. That should work, when it does, restart your computer and re-run the HP Update. At that point, everything else should update.

Answer (score 0):

I have had trouble with HP update from time to time. A clean uninstall and reinstall has always seem to fix it.
I use Revo Uninstaller to kill the old version, and then get the softpaq that is current for the update.